# Prolog predicate makelist

Tags: recursion, prolog

Define a Prolog predicate `makelist/3` such that `makelist(Start, End, List)` is true if
List is a list of all integers from the integer `Start` to the integer `End`. For example:

```
makelist(3, 7, [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]) should be true.
```

Can't understand why my code doesn't work

```
makelist(H, L, _) :-
    L is H+1.
makelist(H, L, List) :-
    append([], [H], List), H1 is H+1.
makelist(H1, L, List) :-
    append(List, [H1], List1), last(List1, R),
    R \= L+1, makelist(N, L, List1), N is H1+1.
```

Comment: Your first clause would immediately succeed if you queried `makelist(3, 4, [x,y,z])` for example since `4 is 3+1` would succeed. `[x,y,z]` could literally be any list, and it would succeed. In your second clause, `H1` is evaluated as `H + 1` but `H1` is never used. Your third clauses uses `last/2`. Where and how is it defined?

Comment: @lurker `last/2` is predefined in SWI- Prolog. I didn't know that either

Comment: @Shevliaskovic thanks! I'm always finding new SWI predicates that aren't in GNU. :)

Comment: @user3612140 - Think about the simple (base) case. What does it look like? I would suggest it's the case where `H` and `L` are the same. So your base case predicate might be, `makelist(H, H, ?)` (what would `?` look like?). And then think about how you would get to the base case recursively from the general case.

Comment: The `last/2` predicate is a **library** predicate in SWI-Prolog, not a built-in predicate. It's defined in the `lists` module which, by default, is auto-loaded when a call to one of its predicate is found.

Comment: @PauloMoura yes, I'm aware. I didn't assume it was built-in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your code, let's take your predicate and examine what is what you really need to do:

```
% makelist(X,Y,L)
```

Since your recursive call is increasing by 1 the first parameter, let's call it X, then your base case would be when X is the same than Y:

```
makelist(X,X,[X]) .
```

and your recursive call: it will be when X is smaller than Y, you need to increase X and add the value to the list:

```
makelist(X,Y,[X|L]) :-  X < Y ,
            X1 is X + 1 ,
            makelist(X1, Y, L).
```